# Hidden select field in simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I need a **hidden select field** in simple form. I tried few ways but none of it works for me

```
<%= f.input :users, as: :select, :collection => presenter.users.map{|user| [user.id, user.email]}, input_html: {hidden: true } %>
```

I tried adding hide class still the element is visible

```
<%= f.input :users, as: :select, :collection => presenter.users.map{|user| [user.id, user.email]}, input_html: {class: 'hide' } %>
```

Also,

```
<%= f.input :users, as: :select, :collection => presenter.users.map{|user| [user.id, user.email]}, input_html: {:include_hidden => true } %>
```

Can someone tell me is there any inbuild option for hidding select field in simple form?

Comment: I wonder what a hidden select field should be? Hidden fields are text fileds becaue when it is hidden you cannot select anything...

Comment: Actually, I am building a form where I need to add some data in hidden field. But If I add in hidden select field it would be easy for me to parse at backend layer

Comment: What do you say is easier to do with a hidden select input rather than a normal hidden input? at the end is just an input with a name and a value, it should be the same on the server side.

Comment: @arieljuod I have to save array of integer based on user selection and deselection. If I take hidden select field so it  will go as an array of integers in backend layer no extra manipulation. Whereas If I take hidden field so at backend Layer I need to do JSON.parse() and splitting the string. In front layer I need to maintain extra manipulation by merge array of integers.

Comment: add `:style => "display:none;"` to hide an element